# Rename table taking too long on MySql 8

Tags: mysql-8.0, ddl, rename

We recently upgraded from MySql 5.7 to 8 and have run into this issue. We have a rename table operation that runs every minute. It used to take a fraction of a second, but now it takes over 6.0 seconds, effectively halting everything else.

We have been able to narrow the issue down to views. We have a bunch of views that reference the table that's getting renamed. We see normal processing time if we get rid of the views. Has anyone else seen this? How would you recommend solving this issue? Also, this was not a problem in 5.7 so I would love to learn more about what changed in Mysql 8 innodb engine that is causing this.

We have tried the ddl-threads related configuration, but it wasn't helpful. Rename and alter the table; both operations take the same time. The following is the summarized query profiling information:

```
+----------------------------+----------+
| Status                     | Duration |
+----------------------------+----------+
| checking permissions (86x) | 0.065414 |
| cleaning up                | 0.008848 |
| closing tables             | 0.000018 |
| freeing items              | 0.028777 |
| Opening tables (7x)        | 0.006327 |
| query end                  | 0.000058 |
| waiting for handler commit | 0.083776 |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Created a mysql forum post as well -- https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,722493,722493#msg-722493